# Multiple docker-compose files - print resulting, merged docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running Docker compose merging multiple docker-compose-yaml files like:

```
docker-compose -f docker.compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml -f docker-compose.X.yml -f docker-compose.Y.yml up
```

As it would help a lot for debugging, is it possible to print the resulting merged docker-compose-yaml file that docker-compose uses?

Simplified Example:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
> version: '3'
> 
> services:
>  nginx:
>     image: nginx:latest

$ cat docker-compose.dev.yml
> version: '3'
> 
> services:
>   nginx:
>     build:
>       context: nginx
>       dockerfile: Dockerfile

# Show merged result 
$PRINT_MERGED_DOCKERFILE_COMMAND -f docker.compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml
> version: '3'
> 
> services:
>   nginx:
>     build:
>       context: nginx
>       dockerfile: Dockerfile
>     image: nginx:latest
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using docker-compose config will show the merged docker-compose yaml:

https://medium.com/@pscheit/docker-compose-advanced-configuration-541356d121de

```
docker-compose -f docker.compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml config
```

It will also print the resulting variables that are used which is also quite helpful for debugging.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I had trouble splitting a `docker-compose.yml` into a base `docker-compose.yml` and a `docker-compose.override.yml`, and automating your answer as following helped me tremendously with narrowing down problems: generate base config dump: `docker-compose config > base.yml`, and then split the config step by step and confirm the base config stays the same: `docker-compose config > new.yml && diff base.yml new.yml`